# g++ cannot find header file

Tags: c++

I am migrating from Java to C++. It seems that C++ makes classes declaration in separate files, difficult. So I need your help,

in my main.cpp:

```
#include "Sphere.h"

using namespace std;
.....
...
..

int main( void ) {
   Sphere *earth = new Sphere(sphere_start ,sphere_end);
...
..
.
```

in my Sphere.h

```
class Sphere
{

    public:
        Sphere(int,int);

}
```

and in my Sphere.cpp

```
#include "Sphere.h"

using namespace std;

int sphere_start, sphere_end;   

Sphere::Sphere (int a, int b)
{
    sphere_start = a;
    sphere_end = b;
}

void Sphere::render(int i) 
{
   ....
   ..
   .

}
```

This is the very basic code that I think causes the following error:

```
main.cpp:14:20: fatal error: Sphere.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphere.h must either be in the same directory as each file that includes it, or the compiler must be directed to search the directory in which Sphere.h is located.

Comment: all the file are in the same directory

Comment: How one could "debug" this problem, when it is clear that all header files are in place, all necessary dev-packages installed and the source file refer to the correct header path, but the compiler still fails to find the header file.

Comment: @AdamL.S. If a compiler fails to find a header file that exists in a known path, the probable cause is failure to specify the root of the path in the compiler invocation. Conventionally, the option is -I. e.g. if header foo.h exists in /usr/include, #include <include/foo.h> will fail unless either the option -I/usr/ is used, or the compiler is invoked in /usr/.

Answer (score 6):

**You need to add to your compile command a path to where the header files can be found.**

If your header is in the `headers` directory add `-Iheaders`:

```
g++ -o main.o -c -Iheaders main.cpp
g++ -o sphere.o -c -Iheaders sphere.cpp
g++ -o app main.o sphere.o -L.
```

Or whatever your files are ...

Answer (score 2):

You should post your command line, but my guess is that you should tell the path to the header files to the compiler. If you're using linux try this:

```
g++ main.cpp shpere.cpp -I<path_to_Sphere.h> -o main
```

Answer (score 1):

Two potential errors:

- Is Sphere.h in the same directory as main.cpp?
- Is Sphere.h named Sphere.h and not sphere.h?